# How to change color of menu icon on custom action bar?

Tags: android, android-toolbar

Im using custom theme:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
```

I want to change colors of all icons and label on my appbar to white, but cant do this because my theme is light and if I write DayNight like this `parent="Theme.AppCompat.DayNight.NoActionBar"`it will not change anything.

I have already changed label text color by java code

```
Toolbar myToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.my_toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(myToolbar);
        myToolbar.setTitleTextColor(Color.parseColor("#ffffff"));
```

but I still cant figure out how to change this icon with three horizontal dots color.
Anyone can help me to solve this problem?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, define a style that sets `colorControlNormal`, making sure to derive from one of the `ThemeOverlay` styles:

```
<style name="MyTheme" parent="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar">
    <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/your_color_here</item>
</style>
```

Then, apply this style to your toolbar in your layout:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:theme="@style/MyTheme"/>
```